# Why am i getting an unclosed parenthesis error in python 3.11?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a Galaga-type game and trying to size down my player sprite.

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int self.size[0]*0.5), (int self.size[1]*.5))
```

and I am getting the errors

```
"(" was not closed Pylance [ln15, col44]
```

and

```
"(" was not closed Pylance [ln15, col57]
```

Comment: `(int self.size[0]*0.5)` is not valid syntax. What operation were you trying to perform there?

Comment: @user2357112 I am trying to divide the size of the sprite in half

Comment: `int(...)` not `(int ...)` It's a function.

Comment: @tadman: Well, constructor, technically, but yes, the syntax is identical for any callable.

Comment: Presumably the parentheses error is on the previous line to this one.

Comment: @ShadowRanger A constructor function, or at least it's listed as a "built-in function" in the docs. Python seems a little mixed on the *functionness* of it.

Comment: Yeah, I wish the docs were a little more precise. The builtin-functions lists contains quite a few types (to be fair, some, like `map`, `filter`, etc, *used* to be functions but were reimplemented as iterators).

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you use functions to convert types instead of type casting operators. To convert `self.size[0] * 0.5` to an `int`, use the function: `int(self.size[0] * 0.5)` instead of a type casting operator `(int self.size[0] * 0.5)` (this is not valid Python syntax).

```py
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, int(self.size[0]*0.5), int(self.size[1]*.5))
```